# I need a "raw id" widget for a ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

one of my models has a **ManyToMany** field.
I'm using a **ModelMultipleChoiceField** with the default widget (**SelectMultiple** widget) at the form.

**The problem:**
There are about 50k options for this field and it's taking ages to load.

I want to change the widget to CharField and enter each PK separated by a comma (like the admin raw_id_field).

**Questions:**
What is the best approach to do this? Did somebody already do a widget for this?
Shoul I create my own Widget or Field?

Thanks!

Comment: May be if you had 50+ option you should use lazy loading for this field with AJAX. For example with django -select2 https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need selection of items in separate window, like in admin, then writing such widget is quite simple. With following widget you will be able to enter comma-separated list of pks:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

class ModelMultiRawInput(forms.TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value:
            value = ','.join([force_text(v) for v in value])
        else:
            value = ''
        return super(ModelMultiRawInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        value = data.get(name)
        if value:
            return value.split(',')
```

You would normally use this widget like that:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), widget=ModelMultiRawInput)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ManyToManyRawIdWidget`?

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L205

*Disclaimer: Haven't tried it myself, came across it while digging through the source code for something else.*

Comment: I can't add that widget just like that. Needs extra JS and resources from the admin. Hacking that would look dirty.